# mongo query from shell

Tags: mongodb, shell

I am executing this query directly from shell.

```
mongo xx.xx.xx.xx:27017/dbname --eval 'rs.slaveOk();db.collection_name.find({"date_time":{$lte:"2017-03-11 05:45:37",$gte:"2017-03-10 23:45:37"}}).count()'
```

Their is no output from from this query.

The query stuck while connection

Comment: What is the data type of "date_time" ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "date_time" attribute is of date type.
Also add proper indexing on fields.

and while doing range query with date better to use ISODate instead of string.

For Ex:

```
items.find({
    created_at: {
        $gte: ISODate("2010-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2010-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")
    }
})
```